# Как сократить строку поиска элемента и переписывание его значение в jquery?

Tags: jquery

вот пример можно ли сделать короче через end или что -то еще чтоб мог один раз найти элемент получить значение и повторно не ища его переписать его значение

```
var val = $(this).parent(".product-count").find("input").val();
$(this).parenr(".product-count").find("input").val(val-1);
```

можно что-то типа этого ?

```
$(this).parent(".product-count").find("input").val().end().val()-1;
```

Comment: `$(this).parent('.product-count').find('input').val((index, val) => --val);` как вариант.

Comment: у вашего this и этого инпута, очевидно один родитель. Так что они соседствуют. в зависимости от структуры разметки, можете использовать `$(this).next('input').val(....)`  и аналогичные функции, ибо `parent().find()` тут не к месту, да и вообще, использовать `parent()` не очень то хорошо, т.к. смена вертки  однозначно приведет к поломке кода. Лучше уж брать `closest()`.

Answer (score 1):

Да это просто. Сохранить результат с dom в переменную как у вас и было (только не само значение, а элемент дом input)

```
var val_input = $(this).parent(".product-count").find("input");
val_input.val(val_input.val()-1);
```